# Determine correct data type

Tags: java, string, integer, return

The following piece of code is not compiling.

As I understand it, the dayCounter method should be passed the dayCheck integer from the earlier code (which is the main method?). In the dayCounter method, this integer will be referred to as dayNumber. The string dayName will be assigned a value based on the value of the integer dayNumber. Then the line "return dayName;" should return the string dayName as the output of the dayCounter method.

I think the problem is either with the line:

```
return dayName;
```

or with the line:

```
static int dayCounter(int dayNumber) {
```

I tried changing the former to:

```
static String dayCounter(int dayNumber) {
```

because I thought that might mean that the dayCounter method was able to return a string - but that didn't help.

I know it's some kind of confusion between integers and strings.

```
class WhatDayIsIt {
    public static void main (String[] arguments) {

        int dayCheck = -1;

        if(arguments.length > 0)
            dayCheck = Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]);

        System.out.println("The day today is " + dayCounter(dayCheck));     

    } 

    static int dayCounter(int dayNumber) {

        String dayName;

        if (dayNumber == -1)
            dayName = "No day given";

        switch (dayNumber) {
            case 1:
                dayName = "Monday";
            case 2:
                dayName = "Tuesday";
            case 3:
                dayName = "Wednesday";
            case 4:
                dayName = "Thursday";
            case 5:
                dayName = "Friday";
            case 6:
                dayName = "Saturday";
            case 7:
                dayName = "Sunday";

        }

        return dayName;

    } 
}
```

Comment: In your method "dayCounter" you're returning dayName which is a String.  But the method signature says it will return an int... you need to return the type you say you're going to.

Comment: "*but can't quite put my finger on why it's not compiling*" usually compiler shows what it complains about. What is your error message?

Comment: `static String dayCounter(int dayNumber) {`

Comment: If you're using an IDE like Eclipse it will highlight your errors and tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Craig, you said "I tried changing the former to: static String dayCounter(int dayNumber) {" -- what error did you get when you tried this?

Comment: "*I tried changing the former to: `static String dayCounter(int dayNumber) {` ... - but that didn't help.*" Actually it did help you. You simply have more problems than you expect and solving one of them showed you another. You should pay more attention to error messages you are getting from compiler. Also some of your problems are with logic so compiler will not be able to show you these (hint: you should read about `default` case, and what `break` is `switch` is used for).

Comment: Also, the name `dayCounter` is not very clear for a method that returns the name of the day of the week. Use descriptive, purposeful method names. This method should probably have been named something like `getWeekdayName` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static int dayCounter(int dayNumber) {` states that you are going to return an value of type int, however what you are actually returning is `dayName` which is of type string. Change the method definition to:
`static String dayCounter(int dayNumber){`

You will also want to update your switch case as there are no `break` statements and so your values fall through.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

```
static String dayCounter(int dayNumber) {

        String dayName;

        switch (dayNumber) {
            case 1:
                dayName = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                dayName = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                dayName = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                dayName = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                dayName = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                dayName = "Saturday";
                break;
            case 7:
                dayName = "Sunday";
                break;
            default:
                dayName = "No day given";
                break;

        }

        return dayName;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been really helpful.

I also found that I had to set dayName to an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Make the dayCounter method to return String:

```
static String dayCounter(int dayNumber) { ... }
```